# Why do we take things personally with an adverb but take them easy with an adjective? How can this be justified?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, formality, modifiers, predicate-adjectives

Why do we write *take it personally* or *take it seriously* with adverbs but we also write *take it easy* with an adjective, not *take it easily* with an adverb? How is this switching off between adjectives and adverbs justified? How can you know which to use?

The same question applies to why we can say *hold (him) responsible* but not to *hold him tight*. Why are these not all adverbs after the verb? What does it mean when there is an adjective after the verb? Isn't *responsible* an adjective? Isn't *tight* an *adverb*?

How can this inconsistent use of modifiers be understood and explained and predicted by native speakers? How do you know if the modifier applies to the subject or to the verb or to the direct object?

Comment: We say "Hold me tight" and "take it easy" in an informal context. but "hold someone responsible" is 'correct' language.

Comment: 'Hold someone responsible' is an adjectival usage whereas 'take it easy' is arguably an adverbial one (see for instance [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/easy_2), with 'easy' the _flat adverb_). Both depictive [secondary predication] structures, and flat adverbs, have already been covered well on ELU.

Comment: It doesn't need to be justified. Language is what it is, not what somebody thinks it ought to be.

Comment: Could you go back and explain your idea of the difference between adjectives and adverbs? Could you also explain why we might say hold (him) responsible but not hold (him) tight? Where does that difference come from?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Are you making an attempt to help me?

Comment: *Tight*, like *easy*, is both adjective and adverb - consult a good dictionary like Merriam-Webster. And it should be obvious that "hold him responsible" is a different structure to "hold him tight", if you think about what it means. This is multiple questions in one, and needs refinement to find an actual question that can be answered.

Comment: Yes, Elvis - though the Question was worded in such a way I had to re-read every one else to understand it properly. If mine didn't fit, please re-read Stuart's Comment.

Answer (score 4):

They seem to me to be different constructions.

*Take it easy* is a fixed phrase, an imperative meaning "Relax!"
The verb *take* is required, and the *it* is required; you hafta have an object, and it hasta be *it*.
You can't take anything else easy.

- **He took the job/the money/a nap easy* ~ **I want to take that/those/someone easy*

Adverbs, however, have no such restrictions

- *He took the money stealthily, and rapidly.*

So adverbs are the norm, but there are some idioms around that don't work the same way.

Comment: +1 Makes no difference to the point, but there's one more object available, at least in UK English: *things*